# PhpStorm 7.1.3, XDebug 2.2.3, Symfony 2.4 - WebTestCase not found

Tags: symfony, xdebug, phpstorm

I'm getting the following error when attempting to run my own Symfony unit tests in PhpStorm:

```
/usr/bin/php /home/kevin/www/src/Blah/MyBundle/Tests/Controller/HomeControllerTest.php
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase' not found in /home/kevin/www/src/Blah/MyBundle/Tests/Controller/HomeControllerTest.php on line 8
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /home/kevin/www/src/Blah/MyBundle/Tests/Controller/HomeControllerTest.php:0

Fatal error: Class 'Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase' not found in /home/kevin/www/src/Blah/MyBundle/Tests/Controller/HomeControllerTest.php on line 8

Call Stack:
0.0002     234112   1. {main}() /home/kevin/www/src/Blah/MyBundle/Tests/Controller/HomeControllerTest.php:0


Process finished with exit code 255
```

Some research has informed me that I may have to point PhpStorm/Xdebug to Symfony's bootstrap and/or test suite XML file, but I'm not sure how to do that in PhpStorm.  Nothing is jumping out at me in the various config screens.  Please help.

Comment: Settings -> PHP -> PHPUnit -> there are inputs for bootstrap and config

Comment: Awesome. :)  If you make your comment an answer, I'll upvote and mark it as such.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Although I'm using IntelliJ IDEA, the configuration is the same, so:

Settings -> PHP -> PHPUnit - there are inputs for bootstrap and config